# How do I access the page slug in the layout file in Next.js (with the app folder)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Using the new app folder in a nested layout, I have a header. Let's assume the path for all the pages in that path are `www.mysite.com/some-slug`. I have a signup button in my header (which is part of the layout), and I want it to send the user to `www.mysite.com/some-slug/signup` but I can't understand how to access the slug. I see the new `useRouter` doesn't have a query anymore, and I don't have access to the page's `context` as I am one level above the page.

I use Next.js version 13.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can read on the [doc](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/file-conventions/layout), a `Layout` in a dynamic segment gets past a second parameter called `params`, which contains the slugs. For example:

```
// app/[slug]/Layout.js 

import Link from "next/link";

export default function Layout({ children, params }) {
  return (
    <main>
      <Link href={`/${params.slug}/signup`}>Signup</Link>
      {children}
    </main>
  );
}
```